# EntityQuery condition "is not equal to..."

Tags: database, 9

### Problem :

I need filtering entities based on the value of a multiple-choice field.
I want my query returns all entities **except those who have a given value** ('`doe`' for this example).

### Actual :

*multiple-choice values*

```
foo|Choice 1
bar|Choice 2
doe|Choice 3
```

*MyController.php*

```
$nodeStorage = \Drupal:::entityManager()->getStorage('node');
$nids = $nodeStorage->getQuery()
       ->condition('type', 'order')
       ->execute();
$entities = $nodeStorage->loadMultiple($nids);
```

### Need :

So I need something like below :

```
$nodeStorage = \Drupal:::entityManager()->getStorage('node');
$nids = $nodeStorage->getQuery()
       ->condition('type', 'order')
       ->condition('field_multiple_choice', '!=', 'doe')
       ->execute();
$entities = $nodeStorage->loadMultiple($nids);
```

How can I do ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found it !

Just reverse the last two parameters of the condition function and use the `<>` operator.

```
$nodeStorage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');
$nids = $nodeStorage->getQuery()
       ->condition('type', 'order')
       ->condition('field_multiple_choice', 'doe', '<>')
       ->execute();
$entities = $nodeStorage->loadMultiple($nids);
```

> As the doc says, [public function
> QueryInterface::condition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.6.x)
> take following arguments :
>
> ```
> condition( $field , $value = NULL , $operator = NULL , $langcode = NULL )
> ```

Comment: Note that the correct database operator for 'not equal to' is '<>'

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to check for the existence of entities with field <> value if that field may be null.

Instead, you must use an orCondition to do notExists OR <>:

```
$query= Drupal::service('entity.query')->get('myentity');
$group = $query->orConditionGroup()
->notExists('my_field')
->condition('my_field', '53', '<>');
$ids = $query->condition($group)->execute();
```